# Запись в файл

Tags: windows, c, c++

При записи в файл командой `fwrite` на `обратный слэш и n (\n)` в файл печатается символ с кодом 10 без перевода строки (Windows-XP).

Comment: Сформулируйте свой вопрос нормально, проставьте корректные тэги.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для перевода строки не всегда достаточно одного символа 10, надо 13 добавлять, не помню до или после 10.

Comment: Правильно - `"\r\n"`

Comment: \r - (carriage return) возврат каретки  
\n - (new line) перевод строки  
windows использует последовательность \r\n в качестве "новая строка", "юникс-стандарт" - только \n  
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Перевод_строки

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 2):

Есть одна деталь. Если файл открыт fopen'ом в текстовом режиме, то 'n' автоматически заменяется парой 'rn', а если в бинарном - не заменяется